# Get VM Name and FQDN

Tags: azure-powershell

Im trying to write a Powershell Query to get the VM Name & FQDM, this is what I have but its not returning the FQDN

```
Get-AzureRmVm | Select-Object Name , @{Name="FullyQualifiedDomainName"; Expression={$_.ToPSVirtualMachine().FullyQualifiedDomainName.Value}} | Format-Table
```

**Update 1**

So I have been able to get the VM, and then the FQDN, and I feel its safe enough for me to do it this was because i know a single RSG will only even contain one VM and one FQDN, so its safe for me to assume they are linked.

```
Get-AzureRmVm | Foreach-Object{Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName} | Select-Object ResourceGroupName, Name , Location , @{Name="FQDN"; Expression={$_.DnsSettings.Fqdn}}
```

However it is slow because of the Foreach, wondered if anyone has any other suggestions on this.

Comment: is there an error message ?

Answer (score 1):

When you create an Azure VM, a public IP resource for the VM is automatically created. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/portal-create-fqdn). None of FQDN is created for a VM in the Azure portal. You could configure it once the VM is created. You could not get the FQDN directly by using the AzureRM.Compute module since the FQDN or DNS name is not a property of VM but is a public IP address configuration.

You can get an FQDN of an Azure VM using

```
(Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $publicipaddress ).DnsSettings.Fqdn
```

[image]

Comment: So If I got all the FQDN's and all the VM info I need, can I then join this in powershell? Currently I have: $Vm = Get-AzureRmVm `
  | Select-Object ResourceGroupName `
                , Name `
                , Location `
  | Format-Table   

$Fqdn = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress | Select-Object @{Name="FQDN"; Expression={$_.DnsSettings.Fqdn}}, ResourceGroupName | Format-Table

Comment: I see you already get what you want, and you could mark this reply as I point you in the right direction.

Comment: I've realised it doesnt actually do what I thought it did, so any further help would be appreciated to reach the answer needed.